# What is the purpose of using type parameters for an empty trait when extending it?

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types, gadt

I have recently come across a code that looks similar to the following.

The question I want to ask is what would be the possible purposes of the Second's type parameters(namely the first type parameter) specified when being extended by the case classes.

I do not see any particular reason to use `A`, `Option[A]` and `Seq[A]` as the type parameters are narrowed down by the extending case classes by `[A <: SomeTrait, B <: AnotherTrait]`.

Am I missing any important points?

```
sealed trait Top[A, B]

sealed trait Second[A, B] extends Top[A, B]

case class ThirdA[A <: SomeTrait, B <: AnotherTrait](
  returnType: Class[A], 
  relation: B
) extends Second[A, B]

case class ThirdB[A <: SomeTrait, B <: AnotherTrait](
  returnType: Class[A],
  relation: B
) extends Second[Option[A], B]

case class ThirdC[A <: SomeTrait, B <: AnotherTrait](
  returnType: Class[A],
  relation: B
) extends Second[Seq[A], B]
```

Comment: I am not sure if I follows, what is the question? I do not see anything weird here.

Comment: I mean what would the type parameters `A`, `Option[A]` and `Seq[A]` be trying to achieve(enforce) here? My understanding is that using Only `A` is the same here as long as the `Second` is empty.

Comment: Well, it is true that you can instantiate a `ThirdA` which has a `Seq[A]` or an `Option[A]` as its A. However, thar does not means that both `ThirdB` & `ThirdC` are bad or useless. They probably exploit the fact that they know they are working on collections /optionals.to provide better implementations.

Comment: To me, the `Option[A]` or `Seq[A]` effectively does nothing from the standpoint of the extending case classes and has no enforcement on how each case class is instantiated in this particular case.

Comment: Yes it is not enforcing anything, but again, I do not see how that make them useless?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered without seeing the context of how it's used.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov In what case do you think this can be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic

> I mean what would the type parameters `A`, `Option[A]` and `Seq[A]` be trying to achieve(enforce) here? My understanding is that using Only `A` is the same here as long as the `Second` is empty.

this [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_algebraic_data_type#Higher-order_abstract_syntax) GADT

```
//  data Lam :: * -> * where
//    Lift :: a                     -> Lam a        -- ^ lifted value
//    Pair :: Lam a -> Lam b        -> Lam (a, b)   -- ^ product
//    Lam  :: (Lam a -> Lam b)      -> Lam (a -> b) -- ^ lambda abstraction
//    App  :: Lam (a -> b) -> Lam a -> Lam b        -- ^ function application
//    Fix  :: Lam (a -> a)          -> Lam a        -- ^ fixed point

  sealed trait Lam[A]
  case class Lift[A](a: A) extends Lam[A]
  case class Pair[A, B](la: Lam[A], lb: Lam[B]) extends Lam[(A, B)]
  case class LamC[A, B](f: Lam[A] => Lam[B]) extends Lam[A => B]
  case class App[A, B](f: Lam[A => B], la: Lam[A]) extends Lam[B]
  case class Fix[A](f: Lam[A => A]) extends Lam[A]
```

doesn't make sense because `Lift[A]` can be obtained as `new Lam[A] {}`, `Pair[A, B]`  as `new Lam[(A, B)] {}`, `LamC[A, B]` as `new Lam[A => B]`, `App[A, B]` as `new Lam[B] {}`, `Fix[A]` as `new Lam[A] {}`, and moreover `App[X, A]` is the same as `Fix[A]` :)

Well, yes, but objects of those types can be obtained having different objects firstly. For `Lam[A]` you need an `A`, for `Pair[A, B]` you need a `Lam[A]` and `Lam[B]` etc.

Similarly, yes, `ThirdB[A, B]` is `ThirdA[Option[A], B]` and `ThirdC` is `ThirdA[Seq[A], B]`. But to have objects of those types you need to have different objects firstly. In order to have `ThirdA[A, B]` you need objects of types `Class[A]` and `B`,  in order to have `ThirdB[A, B]` through `ThirdA[Option[A], B]` you need objects of types `Class[Option[A]]` and `B` but you can have `ThirdB[A, B]` directly just via `Class[A]` and `B`, in order to have `ThirdC[A, B]` through `ThirdA[Seq[A], B]` you need objects of types `Class[Seq[A]]` and `B` but you can have `ThirdC[A, B]` directly just via `Class[A]` and `B`.

For example you can match on `ThirdA`, `ThirdB`, `ThirdC` and write some logic depending on type. So you can specify your general logic for `Option` and `Seq`.

So actually this depends on what `SomeTrait`, `AnotherTrait`, `Class` are.

Comment: Actually in Scala it should be `Fix[A](f: Lam[(=> A) => A])`